# React Final Form reset form fields and validation but retain submitSucceeded

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form, final-form

I'm using React Final Form to display a form and handle form submission. The scenario is that I want to clear all the form fields on a successful submission but show a submit success message which is bound to the final form `submitSucceeded` FormState property.

If I use `form.reset()` this clears all fields and validation but also clears the `submitSucceeded` FormState.

```
callback: event => {
         handleSubmit(event).then(() => {
              form.reset();
          });
    },
```

I can achieve this result by manually going through each form and removing the field value and then resetting the field state. The problem is I want to apply this to any number of forms and don't want to manually overwrite each field but instead automatically reset all fields.

```
callback: event => {
     handleSubmit(event).then(() => {
          form.change('name', undefined);
          form.resetFieldState('name');
          form.change('email', undefined);
          form.resetFieldState('email');
      });
},
```

Any help here is appreciated!
ref: https://final-form.org/docs/final-form/types/FormState

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to achieve this by looping through all form posted `values` and resetting each individually:

```
const submitForm = async (values, form) => {

    // Do something on form submit here

    // Reset form fields, note in a real world scenario
    // this would be inside a success callback
    Object.keys(values).forEach(key => {
        form.change(key, undefined);
        form.resetFieldState(key);
    });
};
```